# Initialize one or many expo-av audio object?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-native, expo

I have a list of audio files that I need to be able to play and I am using Audio from expo-av library in React Native. I am wondering what the best practices are for handling playback of a list of audio files. The requirement is that playback should be done from the list; in other words, we don't want to navigate to a different screen component to handle playback.

I would like to separate concerns of the media list component from the actual player. So "MediaList" would be responsible for listing the audio files, and "Media" component would be responsible for handling the playback. In this case it makes sense to initialize expo-av Audio object in each Media component. This makes separates concerns of Media and MediaList, however, I this also looks like a performance issue since there are so many Audio instances.

So my question is, does having an Audio sound object for each Media instance make sense from performance/resources perspective? Or  should I only have one Audio sound object and re-use that every time I want to play any file? The question is pretty broad without code but I hope someone can provide some direction on the best approach.